# Windows 10 slow boot even after fresh install [WPR log attached]

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

It's taking too long for my laptop to boot even after a fresh install with only few software installed.
I've tried to disable fast startup, updating windows and driver versions to latest, removing Startup applications from task manager but nothing helps.
After the HP loading screen, blank (black) screen is displayed for very long and then the login screen appear. Even after login, windows remain slow for few minutes before I can use it normally.

I used Windows Performance Record to trace the boot process but I'm not expert at WPR and WPA tools. Can someone take a look and let me know what's taking all the boot time?
[image: WPA1]

[image: WPA2]

The link to WPR's etl file is here if you need more information.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d3LAEnhmOWE_VvGUhRuVHGA7y6Mvi48u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the CPU type (i3, i5, i7) and what is the hard drive speed?

Comment: @John It's a SATA 5400RPM. Laptop HP pavilion 14-ce0052tx with 8GB DDR4 RAM and Intel i5 8250U. I have checked the disk and no bad sector found..

Comment: The drive is slow and the major reason why it is slow to start up.  I have seen that many times. Consider whether you can replace it with an SSD drive to speed things up.

Comment: Check your drive speed and health with the following tools and share with us the result: Crystal Disk info & Crystal Disk Mark

Comment: So I installed M.2 NVMe SSD and put Windows on it to make it primary boot device and the difference is day and night. Now boot time is like 10 sec. I should have tried it sooner. Thanks guys!